# Get different data from the GCM

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

I need to get from the database different messages every time. I explain, when there is a new question in the database, I want the user to get a message like "New_Question". If there is new answer int the database, I want the user to get message like "New_Answer". This way i can do different thing when receiving a message from the GCM. How can I do it?
Farther more, I would like to get an object that is not a string from the GCM. Is it possible? and How can I do it?

Here is some of my code:
My onMessage function in the GCMIntentService class:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}
```

My onReceive function in the MainActivity:

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
        WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());


        // Releasing wake lock
        WakeLocker.release();
    }
};
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. You didn't mention what code you are using on your server side to send the messages, but anyway you can send whatever you want, or to be more exact, you can send key/value pairs up to 4096 bytes. For instance, you can send a "question" key or an "answer" key based on the state of your database. Or you can always send the same key with different values to determine the message type.
2. What types do you want to get? Any type can be sent as String and parsed by the Android app.

Comment: Thanks! I would like to get String and a object that I made. Can you tell me where in the code I get this values? And how I get them?